# How can I inform tag wiki reviewer that no text has been copied from external sources?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I'm watching the review progress of the tag wiki edit I've made for the [keccak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keccak) tag, and I'm confused to see that one reviewer has rejected the proposed change on the basis that it "copies a significant amount of content from an external source".

I've been writing a [Keccak implementation for Java](https://github.com/Bobulous/Cryptography) for the last six weeks, and all of the new text added in the tag wiki edit was written off the top of my head based on what I've learned of this hash algorithm.

Is there any way I can advise reviewers of this, so that others do not assume that the first reviewer was correct in their assertion? I'd hate for the edit to be rejected on a mistaken basis.

Comment: In this specific case, the review (and accompanying excerpt review) were ultimately approved. I pinged the editor on another meta post they'd commented on, letting them know about this discussion.

Comment: ... "pinged the *reviewer*", that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is exactly one way to communicate with reviewers: the edit summary. There is no facility to communicate with reviewers during the actual review process to dispute reject reasons.

---

I can't tell you why your edit was rejected by one reviewer. It could simply have been a mistake. Another possibility is because it *looks* like a copy/paste from the project's README or Wikipedia page, and that the reviewer was lazy and didn't verify (these sort of copy/pastes are very common).

Comment: Interesting point about including such advice in the edit summary. I'll try to remember to comment on what is and what is not original text in future.